# Javascript Age in Days getElementbyID problem

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I am trying to finish "Age in Days" project, my problem is getting the result in my empty box.
When inspect via Chrome i can't see my result in `id="flex-box-result"`so the results also not seeing. What i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance[Chrome Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AItWD.jpg).

```js
// Challenge Your Age in Days with Prompt

function ageInDays() {
  var birthYear = prompt("What year were you born?");
  var ageInDaysMult = (2020 - birthYear) * 365;
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDaysMult + "days old");
  h1.setAttribute("id", "ageInDays");
  h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
  document.getElementById("flex-box-result").appendChild(h1);

}

function reset(){
  document.getElementById("ageInDays").remove();
}
```

```css
h2 {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex-box-container-1{
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Age in Days </h2>
    <div class="container-1">
    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()"> Click here </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ageInDays()"> Reset </button>
        </div>


        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
          <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the issue.. i can definitely see the div with the id flex-box-result, and also the code you have supplied is working and i can see the result

Comment: It looks fine to me and works when I run it here. Are there any errors displayed in your console ?

Comment: Actually, my main problem i cant have any result, so i thought its problem of "flex-box-result" cant extend  Thanks again! @TajKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your reset button you must put the reset function not ageInDays

`<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="ageInDays()"> Reset </button>`

to

`<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()"> Reset </button>`

Hope this helps.